# Read from a single file and write it to multiple files simultaneously in multi threading

Tags: multithreading, file, io, stream, bytearrayoutputstream

My purpose is to upload the file on primary location synchronously and same time upload same file on multiple secondary locations asynchronously. So can you please help me to implement multi threading for secondary locations writing(e.g. same file to write multiple paths simultaneously while reading it)

Below is a code to read from input stream

```
List<FileUploadMultiLocator> fileUploadList = new ArrayList<>();
FileUploadMultiLocator fum1 = new FileUploadMultiLocator("fileserver0", new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(reposMap.get("D:\\Harisingh\\FileUpload\\Destination1.txt")))));    
FileUploadMultiLocator fum2 = new FileUploadMultiLocator("fileserver0", new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(reposMap.get("D:\\Harisingh\\FileUpload\\Destination2.txt")))));

fileUploadList.add(fum1);
fileUploadList.add(fum2);

while((len=channel.read(byteBuffer))>=0) 
                {
                    itrCount++;
                    totalBytes+=len;
                    baOS.write(byteBuffer.array(),0,len);
                    if(itrCount>=maxIterateCnt)
                    {
                        //primary location writing
                        bFout.write(baOS.toByteArray(),0,totalBytes);
                        // this is for secondary location writing
                        for (FileUploadMultiLocator fileUploadMultiLocator : fileUploadList) {
                            fileUploadMultiLocator.baOS = baOS;
                            fileUploadMultiLocator.totalBytes = totalBytes;
                            new Thread(fileUploadMultiLocator).start();
                        }
                        totalBytes=0;
                        baOS.reset();
                        itrCount=0;
                    }
                    byteBuffer.clear();
                }
```

This is my runnable class to write multiple BufferedOutputStream same time

public class FileUploadMultiLocator implements Runnable{

```
public FileUploadMultiLocator(String fileserver,BufferedOutputStream bFout) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.fileserver = fileserver;
    this.bFout = bFout;
}
@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try 
    {
        bFout.write(baOS.toByteArray(),0,totalBytes);
        bFout.flush();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please ask a concrete question (see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). What did you try so far?

Comment: My purpose is to write file to primary location in main thread.
For secondary locations, it should work as asynchronously, i don't have to wait to complete it.It should not impact my primary location writing performance.
I did try with above code and it works fine with threading but it effects performance of primary location writing depends on number of secondary locations. I want to write in primary location as a main thread and for secondary locations there should be other seperate threads which should not effect primary location writing.